# Copy paste separate data ranges based on a cell value

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have data ranges in Row 1,2,3 and 4 for columns A:Q. I am trying to create a VBA so it does the following:

Copy Row 1 A:Q, drag and paste n number of rows based on cell O12 starting on Cell A17.

Copy Row 2 A:Q, drag and paste n number of rows based on cell O12 but the paste range should be after what has been pasted for Row 1 range.

Repeat for Row 3 and 4.

So for say of cell O12 states 4, i should be getting 16 rows 4 for each row dragged down.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub CopyJournalLines()

' Works out last cell with data in columns A or B, copys row 2 and paste within that range (from startrow)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim LastRow As String
Dim StartRow As String
Dim Copyrange As String
Dim LastYRow As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Find the last row of data on Concur Extract sheet

Set ws = Sheets("Invoicing")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A:B").Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

' Setting range on Test to copy formulas accross into

StartRow = 17
LastRow = rng1.Row + 1
LastYRow = rng1.Row + 2

If LastYRow < 21 Then
    LastYRow = 19
End If

Set ws = Sheets("Vision Import Sheet")
Let Copyrange = StartRow & ":" & LastRow
Let LastYCell = "AB" & LastYRow

' Clear previous content - limited to clear first 1000rows

Rows("17:5000").Cells.Clear
'Selection.ClearContents

If LastRow < 17 Then
    GoTo End1
End If

' Copying & pasting  row with correct formulas

Rows("1:5").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Copy

Rows("17:17").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Rows("17:17").Select
Selection.Replace What:="#", Replacement:="=", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

Rows("17:17").Select
Selection.Copy

Rows(Copyrange).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Rows("1:5").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End1:
Application.CutCopyMode = False    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy/paste method should be put in two loops corresponding to two parameters: the number of lines to copy and the number of copies per line.

For the following code, you can choose to copy in the format 111222333 or in the format 123123123 by commenting and un-commenting the two lines that calculate the iCopyRow parameter.

```
Sub CopyJournalLines2()
    Dim wsInv As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim iStartRow As Integer
    Dim iNumCopies As Integer
    Dim iNumLines As Integer
    Dim iCopyRow As Integer
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Dim PasteRange As Range

    Set wsInv = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Upload")

    With wsInv
        .Rows("17:5000").Cells.Clear
        iStartRow = 17
        iNumCopies = .Range("O12").Value
        iNumLines = .Range("P12").Value
        For i = 1 To iNumLines
            Set CopyRange = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 17))
            iCopyRow = iStartRow + (i - 1) * iNumCopies '---Copies lines in order 111222333444 etc.
            'iCopyRow = iStartRow + (i - 1) '---Copies lines in order 123412341234 etc.
            Set PasteRange = .Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17))
            PasteRange.Formula = CopyRange.Formula

            If iNumCopies > 1 Then
                For j = 2 To iNumCopies
                    iCopyRow = iStartRow + j - 1 + (i - 1) * iNumCopies '---Copies lines in order 111222333444 etc.
                    'iCopyRow = iStartRow + i - 1 + ((j - 1) * iNumLines) '---Copies lines in order 123412341234 etc.
                    .Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17)).Formula = PasteRange.Formula

                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Stadem, thank you so much for your help. The code seems to work partially. While it is doing what I expected it to do like drag down the lines, however the lines are being pasted as values instead of formulas. Rows 1 to 4 all have formulas.

Comment: Yameen, to copy formulas, use the line  `.Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17)).Formula = CopyRange.Formula` instead of `.Range(.Cells(iCopyRow, 1), .Cells(iCopyRow, 17)).Value = CopyRange.Value`.

Comment: Hello Stadem, thank you again for getting back. This time it is picking up the formula but the formula is not being filled down meaning when pasted and formula has reference to H3 then next row should be H4 and then the one after H5. But all rows are stating H3.

Comment: Oh, OK, I see what you're looking to do. I've updated my answer; this code should work.

Comment: Hello Stadem, thank you for updating. I tried the above code and am facing the same issue. Everything is still static as per what is on the first row reference and is not updating accordingly.

Comment: No change from the previous version, that's strange. Could you post a link to a some screenshots or the Excel workbook you're working with?

Comment: Did not find a way to attach it. Here is the google drive link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxHNUTMrKitNdU5VNlQ0alp4d1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong worksheet in my answer. Check out the latest edit, it should have the problem solved.

Comment: That dd it! You are the best Stadem :)

Comment: Hi there, in the current iteration of the macro the data gets pasted in this form: Line 1 Line 1 Line 1 Line 1 Line 2 Line 2 Line 2 Line 2 Line 3 Line 3 Line 3 Line 3. However is there a way I can have so the loop is like Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 1 Line 2 Line 3?

Comment: Yes. I've added another edit to the code. To switch from 123123123 mode to 111222333 mode, comment out and un-comment the different lines that calculate iCopyRow as shown above.

Comment: IMPORTANT - I also added some functionality so that you can determine how many rows to copy. Previously, the routine always copied 4 rows. Now, you must enter the number of rows to copy in cell P12. If you don't want to have this functionality, simply replace all instances of iNumLines to the number 4.

Comment: Hi there Stadem, it seems that the code is working but it is skipping 3 lines instead of going to the next. Example Line 1 O2 Line 2 P2 Line 3 Q2. Next set should be Line 1 O3 Line 2 P3 Line 3 Q3 but it is actually going to Line 1 O5 Line 2 P5 Line 3 Q5 since P12 value is 3.

Comment: Yes, this is supposed to happen. Line 1 gets copied to rows 2, 5, and 8. Line 2 gets copied to rows 3, 6, and 9. Line 3 gets copied to rows, 4, 7, and 10.

Comment: Hi, yes the copied rows are fine but the value which is a formula is also skipping 3 lines. So say formula for line 1 copied to row 2, 5 and 8 should say O2, O3, O4, but instead the formula is changing with the loop and so the formula is actually showing O2, O5, O8.